# JPQL join 2 tables: Writing jpql

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have 2 tables
First table - Event
Second table - Category

```
@Entity
public class Event {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long eventId;
private String name;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private EventCategory category;
//getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "CATEGORY" }))
public class EventCategory {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long categoryId;
@NotNull
private String category;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Event> events;
}
```

Now I want all the events whose category is some value. I am very new to jpa. Having hard time writing query for this. It will be help if you can help me out.

Edit: I am storing categoryId in events table. I want to be able to be search by category name. category name is saved only in category table. So I think I need to do a join with category table.

Comment: Yeha, find the category someway (EntityManager.find(Object Id)?) and just get the categories. ?

Comment: As I mentioned in previous comment, I am storing categoryId in events table. I want to be able to be search by category name. category name is saved only in category table. So I think I need to join Event table with category table.

Comment: It's the first time you mention that you want to search by category **name**.

Comment: Sorry about that. I had added it in comment to one of the reply below. I have edited my main post accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a query like this:

```
final String query = "SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.category = :category";
```

You can retrieve records with any of a number of means, but here is one:

```
final EventCategory category = ...;
TypedQuery<Event> query = entityManager.createQuery(query, Event.class);
query.setParameter("category", category);
final List<Event> events = query.getResultList();
```

---

*** EDIT ***

By default, the method I illustrated above will search based on the primary key defined for your category object. If you want to search by some other property then you need to specify that in your JPQL:

```
final String query = "SELECT e FROM Event e WHERE e.category.name = :categoryName";

final String categoryName = ...;
TypedQuery<Event> query = entityManager.createQuery(query, Event.class);
query.setParameter("categoryName", categoryName);
final List<Event> events = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work. I am storing categoryId in events table. I want to be able to be search by category name. category name is saved only in category table. So I think I need to do a join with category table.

Comment: @CRS - you need to edit your original question to mention that then. See edit.

Comment: @Perception Using your query requires one to already have the EventCategory -> we already have the Events as in category.getEvents() ...

Comment: @esej - no it doesn't. You can manually create an event category with just the criteria to be searched by, and pass that as a parameter to the query.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, thanks for pointing that out to me. I still think the query should query for the category and not the events - but I guess that is a whole different story.